# How to add incrementally in ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I add incrementally?

```
x = 1

while x < 365 
  x+=x
  puts x
end
```

but this isn't right

Thanks!

Comment: Please define what you mean by "add incrementally". Do you mean you want the sum of the integers between 1 and 365, inclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you need:

```
(1..365).reduce(0) { |memo, i| memo + i }
#⇒ 66795
```

or, in a short form (credits to @Jörg W. Mittag):

```
(1..365).reduce(:+)
```

Here we use standard [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) procedure on [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Range.html). First of all we construct range, containing integers from 1 up to 365. Then we iterate these integers, carrying the total (named `memo` according to ruby convention).

Comment: I think this looks right, essentially it must be calculating as follows, when one item is sold and onwards, so: $1 sold, then $1+$2 sold = $3, then $3 + $3 = $6, $6 + $4 = $10, $10 + $5 = $15, then $15 + $11 = $26 and so on until $365. Do you care to explain the workings of your answer, I'm sort of a newb to ruby, it would be super helpful. Thanks! And I will accept your answer.

Comment: Cheers @mudasobwa, I guess specifically, what does the reduce(0) do? and from what I gather, you've set a range from 1..365, memo is the 1 incrementing/adding, and i is 365? Is it adding to 365? Please clarify. It has to be adding the item sold + the new price, all the way up to $365. Thanks!

Comment: There is no need to assign to `memo`. It is local variable, it will go out of scope anyway.

Comment: @Apane101 I updated an answer with references and explanation.

Comment: You could just say `(1..365).reduce(0) {|acc, el| acc + el }`, which is just the same as `(1..365).reduce(0, :+)`, which in turn is the same as `(1..365).reduce(:+)`, which actually is just `366*365/2` or `66795`.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically speaking, you're looking for the summation of n for n = 1 to y. [According to WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28x%3D1%29%5Ey+x), this summation can be reduced to y(y+1)/2. Therefore, you can calculate this as:

```
x = 365*(365+1)/2 #=> 66795
```

No need for any loops. This code way more efficient; O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: I not sure you need to cite a reference for a formula we all learned in Algebra I (or before), which can be easily derived if one forgets. :-)